# How to use Visual Studio 2022 build tools for NODE JS chocolatey

Tags: node.js, chocolatey, build-tools

I am trying to install Node JS and as of writing this, chocolatey still defaults to Visual Studio 2019 build tools.

I want to ask if it is possible via any simple method to use the VS 2022 build tools instead of the 2019 ones, since they are quite old now.

I tried to install Node JS latest and wanted an option to use the VS 2022 build tools instead of 2019.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Node.js is [opting](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1ba508d51b3057768fa068dc3e279450d498c3d9/tools/msvs/install_tools/install_tools.bat#L42) to install the [visualstudio2019-workload-vctools](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2019-workload-vctools) package. Given you've now got Chocolatey CLI installed, you can use it to also install the [visualstudio2022-workload-vctools](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2022-workload-vctools) package like this from an elevate command prompt:

```
choco install visualstudio2022-workload-vctools
```

If you want to get rid of the 2019 tools, you can do that via Chocolatey as well:

```
choco uninstall visualstudio2019-workload-vctools
```

Note, there may be a reason Node.js is still installing the older tools. If needed you can always uninstall the 2022 version and re-install 2019 (just swap around the commands above as required.)

Comment: Hey thanks that is very helpful, but i have given the complete step by step solution

Answer (score -1):

The way i got it to work was to

1- Install NodeJS once

2- Go to the nodejs installation directory open the ./build_tools.bat via an editor. Replace  visualstudio2019-workload-vctools with  visualstudio2022-workload-vctools.

3-Copying this new script outside the folder.

4- Uninstalling NODEJS

5- Begin a new installation, check the install chocolatey prompt on the installation .

**6- Do not click finish**

7- Copy the old script into the nodjs directory, WHILE keeping the installation program open.

8- Clicking finish to now install chocolatey as usual but now chocolatey will download and install vs 22 rather than 2019